# Nvidia drivers won't show up

Tags: nvidia, graphics

Ok so I built a new PC and ran out of money so I installed Ubuntu from a live USB and when I select 
"Try Linux with out installing" 
I can see in the setting menu that I can select different drivers but if I selected one it wouldn't save however now that it's installed it doesn't show me any different drivers I can use 
I'm running a pny GeForce gt 610

Comment: Iv also just reinstalled Linux so all settings are original and the reason I had to reinstall was because I tried the whole crtl+alt*F1 and manually installed the drivers that downloaded from nvidia website but I believe I messed something up

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Uninstall every NVIDIA related software that you have installed before.

Highlight the Ubuntu entry in the GRUB boot menu and press the <kbd>E</kbd> key.
Add `nouveau.modeset=0` to the end of the linux line - press <kbd>F10</kbd> to boot.
On login screen press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> ... enter  user name and password ...

Now execute the following commands :

```
sudo apt-get purge nvidia*  
sudo reboot
```

Now install the NVIDIA drivers 352 from the official Ubuntu repositories.

Highlight the Ubuntu entry in the GRUB boot menu and press the <kbd>E</kbd> key.
Add `nouveau.modeset=0` to the end of the linux line - press <kbd>F10</kbd> to boot.
On login screen press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> ... enter  user name and password ...

Now execute the following commands :

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install nvidia-352
sudo reboot
```

Comment: Alright I'll give it a try

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution I installed Nvidia-settings and it let me have the driver but now I'm unsure of which one to use